# what does 3rd paramter of public View inflate (int resource, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot) effect on removeView

Tags: android

My English and expression ability is very pool ,so I choose use code to explain my problem.

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/item_image"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"></ImageView>
```

MainActivity as follow:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
private View mInflatedView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    mLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    setContentView(mLinearLayout);
    mLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
    mInflatedView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.item, mLinearLayout, true);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    mLinearLayout.removeView(mInflatedView);
}}
```

Execute above code ,you'll find that removeView has no effect.However if you add View as follow,it will success. Any explanation is appreciate.

```
 mInflatedView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.item, mLinearLayout, false);
    mLinearLayout.addView(mInflatedView);
```

Comment: Please read the [document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html).

Comment: from "boolean: Whether the inflated hierarchy should be attached to the root parameter? If false, root is only used to create the correct subclass of LayoutParams for the root view in the XML." I cann't understand it has something with reomve view effectless.